# Best way to develop shared libraries

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I have 10 developers working on a project. The project contains a number of web applications (wars) and a single shared library (tomcat\lib\sharelib.jar). The development is done in eclipse and a local tomcat.

The sharedlibrary is also a java project in which the code can be modified. When the code is modified, a eclipse builder automatically builds the project into a jar file and copies it into tomcat\lib folder and deletes the old jar file. The allows the developer to test the code as a shared lib while working on it.

A developer will sometimes work on both a webapplication and the sharedlibrary simultaneously. In this case eclipse will get confused giving reference errors on the web applications on classes in the sharedlib. In other words, when a new sharedlib is copied into tomcat\lib folder and the old shared lib is deleted from within a eclipse builder, eclipse looses all references to the jar file (old jar was deleted)  giving compilation errors (reference missing) in the web applications.

The developer then performs a refresh of the workspace, to enforce eclipse to detect the new jar file and resolve the compilation, however that triggers a new build of the sharedlib and cycle continue indefinitely, not resolving the reference errors.

The resolution for the developer is to do a workspace refresh and quickly kill the eclipse builder task before it can copy in the new jar file and delete the old jar file. This refreshes eclipse's references and the compilation errors are resolved.

Is there a better way to handle this ?

The requirement is that any changes done in the shared lib code should reflect on the server immediately enabling the developer to be able to work on the web application and shared library simultaneously.

Comment: can't u stop the auto build of the shared lib? only build when its ready...

Comment: Is it a Maven project?
Is your shared project on github?
I'm going to provide you the correct solution.

Comment: You can convert sharelib.jar to a webservices or one part of ESB project. Developer will call to sharelib by webservices , and don't need to import it to web aplication.

Comment: nafas that is an option, but we are trying to automate as much as possible. So manual builds would be a step back

Comment: dessos, not maven, not git

Comment: simplemind, don't understand, how will that help ?

Comment: BI not possible, to many calls = high latency due to overhead